# Jquery count total values in an each loop

Tags: jquery, count, each

Trying to count each value from a checked input. Independently the code works and returns each value - I need to add them all together outside of the each loop so that I can interrogate the value.

Code is:

```
// Declare empty count 
quiz_count = 0;
$('.questions li ul li').each(function(checking){
    quiz_count += $(this).find('input:checked').val();
});
```

I know I'm close - just can't seem to get there.

Comment: More clarity needed in this question, what do you mean I need to add them all together, create a variable to store the sum of all totals (this can be a global for instance).

Comment: Depending on what the value of the checkboxes is, you may need to use `parseInt()`. Other than that, `quiz_count` should contain the necessary total after the `each()` has completed. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Can you provide a demo showing the issue?

Comment: Issue is that I can receive each value independently (4,3,1,3) - I want to add all the values together and query that count outside of the each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your value is integer use `parseInt` else use `parseFloat`

```
quiz_count = 0;
$('.questions li ul li').each(function(checking){
    quiz_count += ParseInt($(this).find('input:checked').val());
});
```